# Javascript 2d array manipulation (column extraction)

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to shuffle/manipulate columns in a 2d array in JS? Say I have this:

```
data: [
                [0, 29], 
                [1, 71], 
                [3, 106]
            ]
```

Some of the operations I'd like to do

1) Put second column in the place of first.

2) Insert a new column in the middle.

3) Delete a column.

All I can think of is a for loop for every operation.

1)

```
function movecolumn(index, newIndex)
{
 var temp = [];
 for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
 {
  // first copy the row as-is
  temp[i] = data[i];
  // override moved columns
  temp[newIndex] = data[index];
  temp[index] = data[newIndex];
 }
}
```

And then similar for other operations. Are there any libs or better ways of doing this?

Comment: Do you also need operations on rows? If not, the simplest solution would be to transpose the array…

Comment: Just to clarify: I tend to think of 'columns' vertically. Would this mean that `0, 1, 3` is a column, or `0, 29` is a column?
Additionally, if 0, 1, and 3 are meant to be associative indexes for the other numbers, I think there may be a better way of doing this using JS objects (`{}`, rather than `[]`)

Comment: 0,1,3 is column. No associative indexes as values are not guaranteed to be unique. It's just data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function swap(data, i1, i2) {
    var temp = data[i1];
    data[i1] = data[i2];
    data[i2] = temp
}

function insert(data, index, elem) {
    data.splice(index, 0, elem)
}

function delete(data, index) {
    data.splice(index, 0, 1)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would either create a data structure or iterate through. Although you only need to go to each sub-array as each index other than the entire 2D array. Here are some examples:

```
function delCol(a,col){
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i].splice(col,1);
    }
}

function swapCol(a,col1,col2){
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        var t = a[i][col1];
        a[i][col1] = a[i][col2];
        a[i][col2] = t;
    }
}

swapCol(data,0,1); //Swap column 0 and 1.
```